# Python calculating area of rectangle for elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a list like that and I want to calculate the area of rectangle for elements of this list.

```
list = [(3,4),(10,3),(5,6),(1,9)]
```

output = `12, 30, 30, 9`

I tried this code but output is `12,12,12,12`

```
list = [(3,4),(10,3),(5,6),(1,9)]

def calc(x,):
    for i,j in list:
        return i*j


print(list(map(calc, list)))
```

Comment: `[x*y for x,y in your_list]`

Comment: you mean you want to calculate the area of the quadrilateral? or the rectangle bounded by 0,0 and the x,y pairs in your list?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the usage of `map()` is wrong. What map does is apply the function on each element of the iterable and replaces that element with the returned value.

For your list, each element is a tuple of two elements so your `calc()` should he something like this:

```
def calc(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```py
def calc(lst):
    final = []
    for i,j in lst.items():
        final.append(i * j)
    return final
your_list = [(3,4),(10,3),(5,6),(1,9)]
print(calc(your_list))
```

Comment: i have to do this process with map function :S

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier you can just add a list inside the function `calc()` and return the list and it should return `[12, 30, 30, 9]`.

```
number_list = [(3, 4), (10, 3), (5, 6), (1, 9)]


def calc(x):
    result = []

    for i, j in x:
        result.append(i*j)

    return result
```

**Edit: As to use the `map` function.**

If you really want to do it your way then you should do it like this:

```
number_list = [(3, 4), (10, 3), (5, 6), (1, 9)]


def calc(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]


result = list(map(calc, number_list))
```

Since the `map` function provides each element of `number_list` then you cannot iterate over it like your solution. Instead just get the two elements of the tuple and multiply them.

Comment: i have to do this process with map function :S

Comment: I added you a solution with map.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_tuples = [(3,4),(10,3),(5,6),(1,9)]
res = list(map(lambda _tup: _tup[0] * _tup[1], list_of_tuples))
```

**Do not** name your variable ***list*!!*** That's a **reserved keyword** in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can `starmap` the `mul` function to the list:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul

lst = [(3,4),(10,3),(5,6),(1,9)]

list(starmap(mul, lst))
# [12, 30, 30, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

calc function requires to be defined correctly here.

def calc(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]

Also list is reserved keyword in Python.